# Getting attribute of a path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to access the `d` attribute of a path created in `Javascript`. The result of printing the path element is:

```
path class=​"coastline"  
 d="M641.2565741281438,207.45837080935186L640.7046722156485,207.0278378856494L640.6985715873882,207.1279196729914L640.8663103175278,207.53837609537672L640.8542041922302,207.73856415298116L641.04637606029"
```

... with a longer path. I can access the class attribute by using the `getAttribute` method on `class`. However, when I try to access the `d` attribute, it gives me `null`. Is there something else I should be doing?

edit: here is how I am currently attempting to access the d attribute (I specifically want the coastline):

```
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(globe.projection).pointRadius(7);
    var coastline = d3.select(".coastline");
    console.log(coastline[0][0]);
    console.log(coastline[0][0].getAttribute('class'));
    console.log(coastline[0][0].getAttribute('d'));
```

Comment: Show your attempt at solving the problem, so we can see where you went astray. Add some code.

Comment: It should be simply `coastline.attr("d")`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`d` attribute of the `SVGPathElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) "is a string which contains a series of path descriptions."

You can get it and set it through the `getAttribute()`/`setAttribute()` methods.
Once interpreted by the browser, the Path Object will contain an `SVGPathSegList`created from this string. This `SVGPathSegList` will itself contain different `PathSegXTo` objects.

You can access this list and modify each of the Path Segments by getting the `pathSegList` property of your path object, which is an ArrayLike Object, but the original string is only accessible through the `getAttribute` method.

```js
var p = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
p.setAttribute('class', 'coastline');
svg.appendChild(p);
// set the attribute
p.setAttribute('d', 'M50,25L60,105L65,65');

// move the third point on x axis after 1 second
setTimeout(function() {
  p.pathSegList[2].x += 50;

  var coastline = d3.select(".coastline");
  // get the attribute with DOM method
  snippet.log('from getAttribute : ' + coastline[0][0].getAttribute('d'));
  // get it from d3 method
  snippet.log('from d3.attr() : ' + coastline.attr('d'));
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: You only need the NS version for attributes in a different namespace e.g. xlink:href. For attributes such as d on a path getAttribute and setAttribute work fine.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, I'm always confused about it, and NS version works so I'm used to use it...

Comment: I see that get attribute should be getting the d attribute. However, it always returns null.

Comment: @AlexPomerenk I edited the answer to show that if your path is correctly set, then it should work. But as pointed out by Lars Kotthof, if your are already using d3, then you should prefer `d3.attr()` method instead of the DOM one. I do prefer `pathSegList` object than parsing a string myself, but that's all personal.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry! I want to not express my opinion clearly, check the following code directly

```js
var p = document.getElementById('test');
// general attribute | property, bi-directional
console.log(p.id);// test
console.log(p.getAttribute('id'));// test

// custom attribute,  <p class='m-test' id='test' data='data'></p> and p.setAttribute('data', 'data'); one-way, only object.getAttribute() works
console.log(p.data);// undefined
console.log(p.getAttribute('data'))// data

// custom property; one-way ,only object.propery works
p.proData = 'property';

console.log(p.proData);// property
console.log(p.getAttribute('proData'));// null
```

```html
<p class='m-test' id='test' data='data'>
  this is a prograph
<p/>
```

you can set the 'd' `attribute` by using setAttribute method, only by getAttribute() method you get value the 'd' attribute.

Comment: If you set by an attribute property you **can** retrieve by attribute and vice versa. You seem to be confusing CSS properties and attributes here.